# grep url from text and access in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts, ansible-template

Team,

I have a text file containing the url that I need to launch using uri anisible module and capture its result to check http_status code is 200 or not. my playbook is below but I am getting error:

The same work when I use a defined variable from the vars file. but it does not work when I use it from the output of GREP result. if I switch my comment it works. that is if I use

```
url: https://'{{ site_from_vars_file }}'
```

```
-
  name: Test connectivity to target servers
  hosts: all
  vars_files:
           - vars.yaml
      - name: "GREP API server name..  "
        shell: "grep 443 $HOME/.kube/config/cluster-user.kubeconfig | awk -F '//' '{print $2}'"
        register: grep_output
        ignore_errors: true
      - debug:
          var: grep_output.stdout_lines
        when: grep_output.stdout != ''

      - name: "Validate site reachability response as 200 okay  "
        uri:
          #url: https://'{{ site_from_vars_file }}'
          url: https://'{{ grep_output }}'
          return_content: yes
          validate_certs: no
        register: uri_output
        failed_when: uri_output.status not in [200]
```

output:

```
TASK [Gathering Facts] ****************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [target1]

TASK [DNS test] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [target1]

TASK [Validate DNS server] ************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [target1] => {
    "msg": "Resolved DNS server 'site.test.com' '69.172.200.109' "
}

TASK [GREP API server name..] *********************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [target1]

TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [target1] => {
    "grep_output.stdout_lines": [
        "site.test.com:443"
    ]
}

TASK [Validate site reachability response as 200 okay] ***************************************************************************************
fatal: [target1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed_when_result": true, "msg": "invalid literal for int() with base 10: \"True, 'end'\"", "status": -1, "url": "https://'{'changed': True, 'end': '2019-09-27 16:52:08.250231', 'stdout': 'site.test.com:443', 'cmd': \"grep 443 $HOME/.kube/config/cluster-user.kubeconfig | awk -F '//' '{print $2}'\", 'rc': 0, 'start': '2019-09-27 16:52:08.241668', 'stderr': '', 'delta': '0:00:00.008563', 'stdout_lines': ['site.test.com:443'], 'stderr_lines': [], 'failed': False}'"}

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************************************
target1                    : ok=5    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems this one is the issue :

```
url: https://'{{ grep_output }}'
```

You need to changes it to below :

```
url: https://'{{ grep_output.stdout }}'
url: https://'{{ grep_output.stdout_lines }}'
```

Your play will look like this now :

```
- name: "Validate site reachability response as 200 okay  "
  uri:
    #url: https://'{{ site_from_vars_file }}'
    url: https://'{{ grep_output.stdout }}'
    return_content: yes
    validate_certs: no
  register: uri_output
  failed_when: uri_output.status not in [200]
```

Comment: awesome that was it.. but one correction:
 url: https://'{{ grep_output.stdout }}'. >>>  url: https://{{ grep_output.stdout }}

no quotes